# What is significance of field characteristic ≠ 2 on solvability of quadratics over the field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, quadratic-forms

In **Number Theory** by Boreivich, he states in the Algebraic Supplement:

> **1. Quadratic Forms over Arbitrary Fields of Characteristic ≠ 2**
> ... Throughout, K will denote an arbitrary field whose characteristic is not 2. [page 390]

and later

> This equation, which can be written in the form
> ξ<sup>2</sup> - (γξ + 1)<sup>2</sup> = 0,
> always has a solution ξ<sub>0</sub> ∈ K for any γ ∈ K (recall that the characteristic of K is not 2).  [Page 393]

It's unclear to me how a characteristic of any value other than 2 guarantees a solution to the quadratic in ξ.

---

In case the question is unclear, here is context:

[image]

Comment: That is because, in characteristic $2$, you cannot apply the general formula;=, as one has to divide by $2$. For the last equation, there's a difference between  characteristic $2$ and characteristic $\be 2$: in the former case,  squaring defines a ring homomorphism, and the  quadratic has a single root.

Comment: If $a^2 = b^2$ in a field then $a = \pm b$. In characteristic $2$, $-1=1$, so nonzero numbers have a unique square root instead of two square roots. If you set $\xi = \pm(\gamma\xi + 1)$ then $(1-\gamma)\xi = 1$ or $(1+\gamma)\xi = -1$. Outside characteristic $2$, at least one of the coefficients of $\xi$ is not $0$, leading to  at least one solution. In characteristic $2$ there is no solution when $\gamma = 1$.

Comment: @Bernard: If that statement was a sufficient explanation, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

In any field, the equation $\xi^2-(\gamma\xi+1)^2=0$ is equivalent to the disjunction of $\xi=\gamma\xi+1$ and $\xi=-\gamma\xi-1$, or equivalently, $\xi=\frac{1}{1-\gamma}$ and $\xi=\frac{-1}{1+\gamma}$. Thus, it has a solution iff $1-\gamma\neq 0$ or $1+\gamma\neq 0$.

This is always true, unless $\gamma=1$ in a field of characteristic $2$.

Putting it differently, the equation is equivalent to
$$
 \xi^2(1-\gamma^2)+\xi(-2\gamma)-1=0.
$$
If $1-\gamma^2=0$, and the characteristic is not $2$, then this is a non-degenerate linear equation, so it has a unique solution.

If the characteristic is not 2 and $1-\gamma^2\neq 0$, this is a non-degenerate quadratic equation with discriminant $4\gamma^2+4(1-\gamma^2)=4$, which always has a square root, so the equation has two distinct solutions.

In characteristic 2, the equation reduces to
$$
\xi^2(1-\gamma^2)-1=0,
$$
which is easily checked to be equivalent to
$$
\xi(\gamma+1)=1,
$$
so it has a (unique) solution iff $\gamma\neq 1$.